# jpa case-insensitive in-clause for a list of string values

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, jpql

I want to know if JPQL is capable of doing a case-insensitive search on a collection of string.

## Scenario:

## Table1:

```
Column1 (int)  | Column2(string)
1                ABC
2                XYZ
```

I am looking for a JPQL query which does something like this

```
from Table1 a where upper(a.column2) in upper(:listOfCol2Values)
```

Can I achieve this without having to change the case at the application code where i set the collection.

Cheers.

Comment: You have to use Criteria Builder for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Reason is that UPPER and LOWER operate to the strings, so they do not take collection as argument.

Comment: Thanks. That unfortunately, sounds like some additional work for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do :

```
from Table1 a where (upper(a.column2) = upper(:value1) 
    or upper(a.column2) = upper(:value2) 
    or ...)
```