# JPQL LOWER Function in IN Expression

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, orm

Is it possible to perform a string function, such as `LOWER`, on an `IN` expression in JPQL?

I'm trying to use a JPQL query similar to this (the query has been simplified for brevity):

```
SELECT e from MyEntity e WHERE LOWER(e.myAttribute) IN (LOWER(?1))
```

However, with Hibernate/Oracle, such a query results in an error similar to the following:

```
WARN  o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 7001, SQLState: 07001
ERROR o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid parameter count for "LOWER", expected count: "1"; SQL statement:
select e.my_attribute from my_entity e where lower(e.my_attribute) in (lower(?, ?, ?)) [7001-197]
```

The generated SQL query is not valid:

```
lower(e.my_attribute) in (lower(?, ?, ?))
```

I believe it should be more like the following:

```
lower(e.my_attribute) in (lower(?), lower(?), lower(?))
```

It's unclear to me from the JPA specification whether string functions can be applied to `IN` expressions, and if not, what a reasonable alternative is. I'm using an `IN` expression instead of `OR` because I have a dynamic number of items in my parameter list, and I'm using `LOWER` because these must be treated case-insensitively.

I'm using JPA 2.0 / Hibernate 4.2 / Oracle 11g/12c. I'd prefer to avoid any vendor-specific code, and use pure JPA/JPQL if possible, however.

Comment: `LOWER` takes a single string argument. Is parameter 1 really a String argument, and if so, why use `IN` ?!

Comment: @BillyFrost Parameter 1 is a _list_ of Strings. I need to apply the `LOWER` string function to _each list item_.

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178290/jpa-case-insensitive-in-clause-for-a-list-of-string-values, which seems to be a duplicate of my question, and seems to indicate that case-insensitive `IN` is not possible.

Comment: and you cant use a List, without separating each out into a separate parameter ... so then they are usable in LOWER (which takes a single argument). And that other question doesn't "seem to indicate" that it is not possible, it SAYS DEFINITIVELY that it is not possible as you want

Answer (score 0):

JPQL is functioning as designed. Its interpreting it right, that's how the function & parameter are defined in your code.

> `IN (LOWER(?1))` clause is stating to apply `lower` function to parameter `1` which in your case is a `list`. And thus you are seeing the error.

To achieve the desired result with Oracle, you can use the inbuilt Oracle Collection type `ODCIVARCHAR2LIST`. So JPQL will look like below:

```
SELECT e 
FROM   myentity e 
WHERE  Lower(e.myattribute) IN 
       ( 
              SELECT Lower(column_value) 
              FROM   table(sys.odcivarchar2list(?1)))
```

**NOTE:** For Oracle 12.2+, you don't need `table` function, so below will work too:

```
SELECT e 
FROM   myentity e 
WHERE  Lower(e.myattribute) IN 
       ( 
              SELECT Lower(column_value) 
              FROM   sys.odcivarchar2list(?1))
```

Comment: Thanks, @amith-kumar, but I'd prefer to avoid vendor-specific content in my JPQL.

Comment: Yeah it does become DB dependent query, but its an option if you really wanna do it through query. I personally would prefer to pass already lower cased list as param to do case-insensitive IN search.